# Jmeter conditional statement on thread group

Tags: json, multithreading, api, rest, jmeter

Is it possible to create a conditional statement on Jmeter thread group? Example I have 3 threads each has different setup and I want to execute depends on the parameter being selected. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Example:

Thread 1 Setup

Users = **100**

Request = **A , B , C**

Request per minute = **6000**

Thread 2 Setup

Request = **D, E ,F**

Users = **20**

Request per minute = **2000**

Thread 3 Setup

Users = **50**

Request = **X, Y , Z**

Request per minute = **4000**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run this or that Thread Group depending on the "parameter" passed you can use [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) to control the number of threads. If you set the number of threads to `0` the Thread Group won't be executed.

Something like:

[image]

Textual representation just in case:

```
${__groovy(props.get('parameter').equals('foo') ? 100 : 0,)}
```

if `parameter` JMeter Property value will be `foo` - the Thread Group will start `100` threads, otherwise it will be `0`

If you want to execute this or that Sampler(s) in the Thread Group depending on the "parameter" value - take a look at [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)